# User interface is not visible when the app runs (only in interface builder)

Tags: cocoa

I'm stuck on a very stupid issue. I've built my mac osx app user interface with Interface Builder (and xcode3).

Now when I run my app I can't see the app window (but only the menu on top).

The MyDocument.xib file is correctly loaded (from xCode navigation sidebar) and I can see my user interface in interface builder.

In my code I haven't changed this method:

```
- (NSString *)windowNibName
{
    // Override returning the nib file name of the document
    // If you need to use a subclass of NSWindowController or if your document supports multiple NSWindowControllers, you should remove this method and override -makeWindowControllers instead.
    return @"MyDocument";
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bad configured ArrayController!

No error messages.. just the interface not showing up

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following methods in the NSApplicationDelegate documentation:

- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag

Answer (score 0):

Each window has an option (checkbox) called visible at start (or something like that; can't check ATM). Doublecheck if that's activated.